# Magento 1: Check if customer has quote

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, quote, sales-quote

How can I filter customers by the fact if they have a quote in the `sales_flat_quote` table? I could `foreach` every customer to check if their email address is located in the `sales_flat_quote` table, but that doesn't sound like a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter that table with its corresponding collection model:

```
$quote = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
         ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
         ->getFirstItem();

if($quote) {
    //customer has quote
}
```

You only need the customer ID.